# Scheduling Algorithm implementation C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write the CLOOK scheduling algorithm and I am a little lost on how to go forward. Here is what I have

```
 queue<int> workQ;
int headPosition;
int temp;
int cyl;
cout << "Enter the number of cylinders: ";
cin >> cyl;
cout << "Please enter the head Position: " ;
cin >> headPosition;
cout << "Enter the request: "; 
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> temp;

        //Enter a '0' to signal the end of inputing request
        if(temp == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Will implement check later to make sure the request is not greater than the number of cylinder        
        workQ.push(temp);
    }

    //Print content of Queue AND put into a vector
    queue<int> tempQ;
    vector<int>request;

        tempQ = workQ;
    while(!tempQ.empty())
    {
        cout << tempQ.front() << " ";
        //Put in vector for easier use
        request.push_back(tempQ.front());

        tempQ.pop();
    }

    cout << endl;
    queue<int> clook; // used to hold the order of the request after scheduling is complete

    //starting the CLOOK algorithm with the head set at 50 by user
    //for(int i = 0 ; i < request.size() ; i++)
    //{}

    int max;
    int min;
            //I didnt include the insertion Sort code but it works fine
    insertionSort(request, max, min);
    cout << max << endl;
    cout << min << endl;

    while(!request.empty())

        for(int i = 0 ; i < request.size(); i++)
        {
          // I am lost on how to go forward here!!
```

The head position is 50 and the number of cylinder is 200. 
The work request is as follow [95,180,34,119,11,123,62,64] and sorted 
I got[11,34,62,64,95,119,123,180]. I basically want to start the head at
50 meaning the CLOOK scheduling should service 34,11 and jump to 180,
then 123,119,95,64,62 (while at the same time keeping track of the head position)

```
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are dozen of implementations available on the net, just google them.
For example http://ashbeecode.blogspot.ru/2011/05/c-look-disk-scheduling-algorithm.html

Comment: unforuntably the code that you provided has numerous error when I tried to compile it. I have no idea if its correct